# WCF is throwing UnauthorizedAccessException after upgrade to .NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, wcf, .net-4.0, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I have a pretty simple client-server ASP.NET app; communication is via WCF service. All worked perferctly in VS 2008, now I upgraded to VS2010 and every time the client code is trying to instantiate a channel to the server:

```
new ChannelFactory<IMemberService>("Members.MemberService").CreateChannel();
```

it throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException` "Access denied".

Were there any breaking changes in the new version, or do I need to add some configuration?

I'm pretty stuck, any ideas would be highly appreciated!

BTW, binding used is basicHttpBinding, I don't know if thats important here.

Thank you,
Andrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please disregard, turned out to be configuration error

Comment: Can you post what you changed in the config? I'm having the same issue. (@Chris had the question)

Comment: @jjnguy: don't remember exactly, it was a year ago :) but I remember it turned out not to be related to WCF at all. Something with IIS configuration